# How to define this function structure in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Let's say I have function that creates a dynamic function and returns it.

`Function` takes data argument of type `String` and returns `String`.

```js
/**
 * @param {String} data
 * @returns {???}
 */
const foo = data => {
    let functionString = 'return data;'
    return Function('data', functionString)
}
```

I would like it to show up in VSCode Intellisense with an appropriate definition. How to document it in JSDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [namepath](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html) to document an inner member. Per the documentation:

> ### Namepaths in JSDoc 3
>
> When referring to a JavaScript variable that is elsewhere in your documentation, you must provide a unique identifier that maps to that variable. A namepath provides a way to do so and disambiguate between instance members, static members and inner variables.
>
> **Basic Syntax Examples of Namepaths in JSDoc 3**
>
> ```
> myFunction
> MyConstructor
> MyConstructor#instanceMember
> MyConstructor.staticMember
> MyConstructor~innerMember // note that JSDoc 2 uses a dash
> ```

Since you want to refer to the returned inner `Function` inside `foo`, you must use the very last option which documents an inner member of a function.

To use namepaths, you must use an identifier so JSDoc can identify the member, and this is achieved through declaring a variable as mentioned in the documentation. You can define your return value as a variable and return the variable. Thus:

```
/**
 * @param {String} data
 * @returns {foo~newFunction}
 */
const foo = data => {
    let functionString = 'return data;'

    /**
     * Notice the idenfier newFunction given to the member
     * You can now document the function here
     */
    let newFunction = Function('data', functionString)
    return newFunction
}
```

With the above, we define the former return value as a variable named `newFunction`. Consequently, we can use namepaths to reference it as `foo~newFunction` as its now an inner member of `foo`, and then set it as the return value of `foo`. You can then return `newFunction`.